# Cannot update identity column for table, even if reseeded or identity_insert is set to ON

Tags: t-sql

I am having a little headache here. I am trying to run a merge statement against an empty table, but it complains that the identity column cannot be updated. here is the code I tried:

```
    DBCC CHECKIDENT('ui_screens', RESEED, 1)
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT ui_screens ON;
    GO
    MERGE INTO ui_screens AS Target
    USING (VALUES(....))
    AS SOURCE (screen_id, ....)
    ON Target.screen_id = Source.screen_id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET 
        screen_id = Source.screen_id,
        ....

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT (
            screen_id,
            ....)
        VALUES (
            screen_id,
            ....)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        DELETE;
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT ui_screens OFF
```

`screen_id` is the column containing the identity and is currently giving trouble. I have reseeded in this script, I have set "`SET IDENTITY_INSERT ui_screens ON`" on my tables. What am I missing? Has this error got something to do with the table having no records in it?

Comment: Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot update identity column 'screen_id'.

Comment: There is no way to update an identity column. As the name implies, `IDENTITY_INSERT` only allows you to supply values for the column in `INSERT` statements, where normally you would not be allowed to. Direct updating is still a no-no.

Comment: that rings true. hold on, let me remove the update line

Comment: slam that down as the answer. tickle me pink, it worked!

Comment: It works because your table is empty and you don't need updates. If you do need updates eventually, you'll have to make it a non-identity column. SQL Server 2012 implements sequences, which give you increasing values without the identity property.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line where you're updating `screen_id = Source.screen_id`. It doesn't make sense to update it anyway since the values would've had to be the same in the first place in order for `WHEN MATCHED` to return true.

You don't need to delete the whole UPDATE statement. You can leave the rest of it to update the other columns.